# How to remove the new line characters from a string?

Tags: elixir

I want to remove all the newline symbols:

```
aaa = """
fdsfds fdsfds
  fdsfdsfds
fdsfdsfds
""" |> String.strip("\r\n")
```

And I get:

```
argument error
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What's wrong with this?

`String.strip` only supports removing one character. That error is thrown as Elixir tries to convert `"\r\n"` to a single character ([source](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/8fa5b6953efab37b5c119daaf82cf270ca1772bb/lib/elixir/lib/string.ex#L808)):

```
iex(1)> s = "\r\n"
"\r\n"
iex(2)> <<s::utf8>>
** (ArgumentError) argument error
```

Moreover, `String.strip` has been deprecated in favor of `String.trim`, which does support a string as the second argument, but that function will only remove the exact sequence `\r\n` from the starting and ending of the string:

```
iex(1)> aaa = """
...(1)> fdsfds fdsfds
...(1)>   fdsfdsfds
...(1)> fdsfdsfds
...(1)> """
"fdsfds fdsfds\n  fdsfdsfds\nfdsfdsfds\n"
iex(2)> String.trim(aaa, "\r\n")
"fdsfds fdsfds\n  fdsfdsfds\nfdsfdsfds\n"
iex(3)> String.trim(aaa, "\r\n") == aaa
true
```

which I doubt is what you want as you said "I want to remove all the symbol of a new line". To remove all `\r` and `\n`, you can use `String.replace` twice:

```
iex(4)> aaa |> String.replace("\r", "") |> String.replace("\n", "")
"fdsfds fdsfds  fdsfdsfdsfdsfdsfds"
```

Comment: `aaa |> String.replace(~r/\r|\n/, "")`?

Comment: @mudasobwa I personally wouldn't use a Regex for such simple cases, but that's certainly a valid solution! I also think in this case my 2 String replace solution would be faster than your Regex one although I haven't measured it.

Comment: Thanks for the `String.trim` tip about the exact sequence.

Answer (score 3):

Escape the newlines

```
"""
fdsfds fdsfds \
  fdsfdsfds \
fdsfdsfds
"""
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imho.